# adding sys.stdout.write output to a variable

Tags: python, parsing, jython

Is there a way to add the output of sys.stdout.write to a variable?  Or is there a better way to do what I am doing in jython:

I have a web address("www.example.com/whateverpage.html") and I want to create a variable which I get my script to click into so the end result must be:

```
HtmlAnchor[<a href="www.example.com/whateverpage.html">]
```

I tried using `pageAnchor = 'HtmlAnchor[<a href="',PageLink,'">]'`

but it didn't work, because it outputs a space between the href and the PageLink variable.  So I figured I was smart(which apparently I am far from :-) and used stdout.write to print with the spaces but when I output it in the script it looks perfect but when I try to save it to a variable and then print that variable I get (None, None, None).

The other way I thought of doing this is to use regexpressions to get rid of spaces but I need the space between 'a' and 'href'

I'm sure there is a simple way I'm just not seeing, can anyone give me any pointers..
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want `pageAnchor = ''.join(['HtmlAnchor[<a href="',PageLink,'">]'])`

Or simply `'HtmlAnchor[<a href="' + PageLink + '">]'`

But it's far from clear, to me, what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much Jcomeau.  ..thats the problem.  The software I am using to extract the links(beautifulsoup) is not the same as I am using to click on pages and navigate(htmlunit).

Answer (score 1):

Try something simpler, [format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) :)

```
>>> addr="www.example.com"
>>> s = "HtmlAnchor[<a href=\"%s\">]" % addr
>>> s
'HtmlAnchor[<a href="www.example.com">]'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Sarnold.  I think I get it now. I didn't know about the \"%s\" I'll play around with it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Lostsoul, the `\"` are there just because you wanted the `"` in the HTML output. It could also have been: `s = "HtmlAnchor[<a href='%s'>]" % addr` -- the `'` wouldn't require quoting in the double-quoted string.

Comment: The % style of format strings is being deprecated slowly, the preferred new method is to use the format function. `"HtmlAnchor[<a href=\"{0}\">]".format(addr)` . See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) for more info

Comment: Thanks JHSaunders, I hadn't heard that yet. Pity, I liked the simplicity of `%`.